# Python, Soup, and grabbing tables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a page that has multiple tables. I am trying to get a table that is called "TabBox", but it seems to be grabbing the proceeding one called "TabBox2". Any ideas?

There is a "TabBox2" that wraps both tables. Seems it is searching for the first instance of "TabBox" regardless of being named "TabBox2" or just "TabBox".

```
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "GroupBox3" })
rows = table.find_all("tr")

table2 = soup.find("table", { "class" : "TabBox" })
rows2 = table.find_all("tr")
```

rows2 should = table2.find

Thank you Game Braniac!

```
       <br />
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" class="GroupBox1">
          <tbody><tr>
            <th><h3>Completion Information</h3></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><table width="578" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" class="GroupBox3">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th width="31%">Well Status Code</th>
                <th width="17%" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center"><strong>Spud Date</strong></div></th>
                <th width="28%" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Drilling Completed</div></th>
                <th width="24%" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Surface Casing Date</div></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">W - Final Completion</td>
                <td><div align="center">12/08/2011</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">02/14/2012</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">12/09/2011</div></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" class="TabBox">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th width="155" nowrap="nowrap">Field Name</th>
                <th width="142" nowrap="nowrap">Completed Well Type</th>
                <th width="108" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Completed Date</div></th>
                <th width="133" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Validated Date</div></th>
              </tr>

               <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                   WOLFBONE (TREND AREA)
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Oil</div>
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">02/14/2012</div>
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">06/04/2013</div>
                </td>
               </tr>

            </tbody></table>
           </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody></table>
       <br />
```

Comment: Is the `id` `TabBox` or the `name` of the table so? Also, where is your sample HTML and code?

Comment: @ Games Brainiac: This is what I have. Again it is "wrapped" in a "TabBox2" header.

Comment: table2 = soup.find("table", { "class" : "TabBox" })

Comment: rows2 = table.find_all("tr")

Comment: I'm a little lost, but I've posted something, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = r"""
      <br />
       <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" class="GroupBox1">
          <tbody><tr>
            <th><h3>Completion Information</h3></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><table width="578" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" class="GroupBox3">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th width="31%">Well Status Code</th>
                <th width="17%" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center"><strong>Spud Date</strong></div></th>
                <th width="28%" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Drilling Completed</div></th>
                <th width="24%" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Surface Casing Date</div></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">W - Final Completion</td>
                <td><div align="center">12/08/2011</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">02/14/2012</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">12/09/2011</div></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="1" class="TabBox">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th width="155" nowrap="nowrap">Field Name</th>
                <th width="142" nowrap="nowrap">Completed Well Type</th>
                <th width="108" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Completed Date</div></th>
                <th width="133" nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Validated Date</div></th>
              </tr>

               <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                   WOLFBONE (TREND AREA)
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">Oil</div>
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">02/14/2012</div>
                </td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap"><div align="center">06/04/2013</div>
                </td>
               </tr>

            </tbody></table>
           </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody></table>
       <br />
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tab_box = soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'TabBox'})

for var in tab_box:
    print var
```

Comment: Thank you. I was finding rows based on the original table, not the second. Sometimes I can't see the most apparent things without help. You are the man!

Comment: @ Games Brainic again thank you. I was using table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "GroupBox3" })
rows = table.find_all("tr")

table2 = soup.find("table", { "class" : "TabBox" })
rows2 = table.find_all("tr")
Instead of table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "GroupBox3" })
rows = table.find_all("tr")

table2 = soup.find("table", { "class" : "TabBox" })
rows2 = table2.find_all("tr")

Comment: Don't know how to '\n' lines in the comments.